# Scala: What is the difference between (a: String) and (a: => String) for argument?

Tags: scala

What is the difference between these two method?

```
def method1(msg: => String) = print(msg)
def method2(msg: String) = print(msg)
```

I can invoke them both.

```
  method1("1")
  method2("2")
```

And they print `12`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called passing argument by name, when argument passed by name and accessed inside function it evaluates again. You can run example code:

```
  def method1(msg: => String) = {
    println(msg)
    println(msg)
  }
  def method2(msg: String) = {
    println(msg)
    println(msg)
  }

  method1({println("Evaluate Arg1"); "Method1"})
  method2({println("Evaluate Arg2"); "Method2"})
```

Output:

```
Evaluate Arg1
Method1
Evaluate Arg1
Method1
Evaluate Arg2
Method2
Method2
```

As you can see in method1 every time you access `msg` it's re-evaluated

Comment: It is other way round , call by name value evaluate at the time of method call and here method 1  is call by name and it's value evaluate at the time of function call and method 2 is call by value which will evaluate prior to method call.

Comment: Yea, it was a typo. Sorry - still might be worth clarifying.

Answer (score 4):

The second one `method2(msg: String)` is call by value method and the first one `method1(msg: => String)` is call by name method.

In call by name, Arguments will not be evaluated until they are being used and it will be also be re-evaluated every time it is being used.

In call by value, Arguments will be evaluated at the time of function call.