# Need help understanding the syntax

Tags: scala

I am Scala beginner.I know the syntax for function declaration

```
def function_name(parameter:return_type):return_type = {function_body}
```

Refering this link https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/scala-in-action/chapter-2/161.
I can't get over the code written there

```
def breakable(op: => Unit) { ... }
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: What is the difference between (a: String) and (a: => String) for argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306284/scala-what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-string-for-argumen)

Comment: @RobinGreen The problem might be the lack of `=` so I can't tell if this is a duplicate or not. Or rather, it is probably a duplicate of two different questions!

Answer (score 3):

This is a shorthand syntax for declaring a function that returns `Unit` (roughly the same as `void` in `C`-like languages).

The definition

```
def breakable(op: => Unit) { ... }
```

is the same as

```
def breakable(op: => Unit): Unit = { ... }
```

This syntax may be removed in later versions of Scala, so best to include the `=` even when declaring a function that returns `Unit`.

---

The parameter is declared as `op: => Unit` which means it is a *call-by-name* parameter. This means that the expression that is passed to this parameter is only evaluated when it is used, and is evaluated every time it is used. In this case it means that you can pass a block of code to `breakable` in a convenient way:

```
breakable {
    println("I have been called")
}
```

Each time `breakable` evaluates `op`, the `println` statement will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

In scala function can take values(pre-computed values or not-yet-computed values) along with function as arguments.

**So, function which takes computed values as argument,**

```
scala> def f(a: Int) = a * 100
f: (a: Int)Int
```

**Example of function which takes a block of code returning `Int` (not yet computed) ,** block of code here could be just anonymous or existing method(not a function; that's where things get messy)

```
scala> def f(a: => Int) = a
f: (a: => Int)Int
```

and to use it,

```
scala> def a: Int = 100 * 100
a: Int

scala> f(a) //a returns Int so confirms a: => Int
res3: Int = 10000
```

In your example, `def breakable(op: => Unit) { ... }` takes a argument which WILLL be computed as `Unit`.

For example, you can pass `println`, which returns `Unit`,

```
scala> def breakable(op: => Unit) = op
breakable: (op: => Unit)Unit

scala> breakable { println("i m learning fp") }
i m learning fp
```

**The other thing you will see is function taking function as argument, as in Functor, Monad etc.**

For example, `map`/ `flatMap` on `List[Int]` would be

```
final override def map[B](f: A => B): List[B]
final override def flatMap[B](f: Int => scala.collection.IterableOnce[B]): List[B]
```

Comment: `op` is not a function parameter, it is a call-by-name parameter, so you need to edit your explanation,